# Force python ssh interpreter to use local data

Tags: python, ssh, local-storage, data-science, interpreter

Ahoi there,

I have a fine running python interpreter in PyCharm. The thing is, my data is big.

My source file are around 20GB in total (satellite data) and my result file from my program around 12GB. The program runs with the SSH interpreter on a very fast GPU machine, but of course he is not finding the source files on my local system... I cant either upload my source data to process it on the server, or upload my result file. Minimum would be 10 hours, but the program runs in like 30min...

Is there any way to force the SSH interpreter to build the file on the server, but use the source files from the local system?

Comment: This is (a) not possible and (b) not a software development problem.

Answer (score 1):

- **Technically you could [pipe some data over SSH](https://www.maketecheasier.com/ssh-pipes-linux/)**: but practically I don't see how it would handle `12GB` (either SSH or remote python would break trying to handle such amount from pipe)
- **So you must be able to read the data from your GPU machine**: placing the data on the server seems the easiest (simple file read) and best performance (everything local to your server), [although you could potentially stream it via a network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137040/whats-the-best-way-to-read-and-parse-a-large-text-file-over-the-network) or other network-based solutions
- **Big data file formats will help with file transfer/read speed**: have a look at file formats like `Avro`, `Parquet`, `ORC`, they are well supported in the data science ecosystem and can [reduce dataset size and increase read speed significantly](https://www.google.com/search?q=parquet%20vs%20csv%20file%20size&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjU0_XSotPxAhXnx7sIHR9kBP8Q2-cCegQIABAA&oq=parquet%20vs%20csv%20file%20size&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIECAAQGDoECAAQHjoGCAAQCBAeUOjQAliE2gJg29oCaABwAHgAgAFBiAGMBJIBAjEwmAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=IdTmYJS_I-eP7_UPn8iR-A8&bih=939&biw=1920&client=ubuntu&hs=gL&hl=en) (so you convert your file locally, copy it over to your server to read it there)